WSL terminal displays subdirectory not present in Windows Explorer
I installed Linux shell using WSL. Cloned my repo and built project. Issue is not everything within project directory is present in Windows and subsequently IntelliJ.
Let's say I'm working on directory /home/Ubuntu/ProjectA/generated-commons and here I have:
-rw-r--r--  1 ubuntu ubuntu 49174 Aug 28 16:45 pom.xml
-rwxr-xr-x  1 ubuntu ubuntu   271 Aug 28 16:45 rebuild_without_publish.sh
drwxr-xr-x  4 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Aug 28 16:45 src
drwxrwxrwx 10 ubuntu ubuntu  4096 Sep  2 09:09 target

Last directory "target" being an issue. Windows in directory \\wsl$\home\Ubuntu\ProjectA\generated-commons contains only first 3. This directory was not part of repository downloaded, but was generated when project was built using script. Originally it was owned by root, but I changed owner using chown command thinking that it would fix the issue.
Can someone explain why can't I access this directory even after changing owner and how to change it, so I can access this directory on Windows?

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Can you add the results of stat target to the question?

Did you get this resolved?  Happy to try to help, but I never saw a follow-up on my question above.

My apologies for late reply, I ended up working with admin from my company on it for quite some time. I'll post as a solution what we ended up with

Sadly, I ended up removing wsl from my machine and reinstalling. Steps we followed:

Removed Linux WSL Update using Controll Panel
Open PowerShell (as administrator) and run the following command to disable WSL: Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux
Open a command prompt (as administrator) and run the following command: dism /online /disable-feature /featurename:Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux /norestart
Open PowerShell (as administrator) and run the following command to disable WSL: Disable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

No. 4 was done from cmd as it wasn't in Controll Panel for some reason. Nevertheless command was executed successfully
